# Why is my particle system rendering differently on my cloud rendering service?

Tags: rendering, particles

I'm making a little isometric low poly scene, and I'm using a couple of hair particle systems to scatter trees randomly over a plane. On my system I have them distributed pretty much how I want them to surround a little cabin I've modelled.

However, when I upload them to Render Street for final rendering, the trees are in an entirely different place. I have rendered it twice and they render in the same location each time on Render Street, but in a different place to my local version.

I also have an emitter system for smoke and that renders identically to mine.

Why is this happening, and is there some way I can 'bake' the hair particle distribution in so it's consistent?

EDIT: The following support page on Render Street goes through baking for particle systems, but this only seems to apply to Emitter systems. There is no cache tab for Hair systems:

https://support.render.st/portal/en/kb/articles/how-baking-works-with-blender-on-renderstreet

Comment: "entirely different place" as in shiftet as a whole .. or more a bit other random shuffle like you used a different seed.? Maybe add some screenshots of both.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the answer to this. For hair systems, click the Convert button in the Modifier tab to convert the hair to meshes. Then delete the particle system itself from the Particles tab, otherwise they'll still render. Obviously save the file before you do this or you'll lose the ability to change your particle system.

Comment: dont be afraid to accept your own answer as right so this question gets markt as answered :)

Comment: I would, I have to wait 2 days as a new user.