# Lodify not working with farm. Scatter/Lodify to RenderStreet

Tags: proxies

I have a ticket with the render farm (RenderStreet) - but timing is a little tight and don't expect feedback from them until Monday so I'm giving the forum a shot.

The issue is basically the proxy portion of the Scatter add-on (Lodify is built into Scatter) renders well locally, but with the farm it is not switching the low poly object to the high poly object.

[image]

Curious if anyone has thoughts, there's a mention about baking on a thread but it seems to be more specific to location of the particles, not about the proxy working:
[Why is my particle system rendering differently on my cloud rendering service?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204744/why-is-my-particle-system-rendering-differently-on-my-cloud-rendering-service)

thanks in advance,

Jay

Comment: Hey Jay,

We sent a reply to the ticket you sent to us on the farm. We can help get the addon to work, just write back and we'll assist.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Marius, I've been working with Sorin on it thank you so much!